# How to get number of all unique permutations of lengh k out of string of length n?

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, permutation

Suppose we are given string `s = "aba"` and `k = 2`. Then the permutations we can make using string characters are

```
aa ab ba
```

So the answer is 3.

If `s = "aabb"` and `k = 2` then possible permutations are

```
aa ab ba bb
```

So answer is 4.

We can use a character only as many as times it is appeared in string or less than that but not more than that.

Is there any formula or some way to find it out quickly?

Note: K is not the number of unique charcters, for eg. `s = "aabbcdd"` the value of k may be `k = 3`.

Comment: This seems better suited for [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/). Please see their [help pages](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more info.

Comment: These stuffs have any meaning for you `C(n,k) = n! /k!(n-k)!` or `A(n,k) = n!/(n-k)!` ?

Comment: See if s= "aabb" and k=2 then possible permutation is "aa" "ab" "ba" and "bb". So answer is 4.

Comment: The answer is yes. These are called permutations of multisets and there is some well written articles on this topic (including a counting algorithm). My favorite is Combinatorial Generation by Frank Ruskey.

Comment: @TraianGEICU , the answer to this problem isn’t as straightforward as you suggest. As an example try finding the number of unique permutations of “aaaaabbbbcccdde” of length 6.

Comment: @JosephWood Did i say that is the answer ? if have distinct elements A(n,k) can be used, but with non-unique elements (as you suggested) identical solution should be removed. The  issue is how to do with non-unique and it's not so straightforward

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

class solution {
 static int findPermutation(String str, int k) {
  boolean[] has = new boolean[26];
  Arrays.fill(has, false);
  int cnt = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
   if (!has[str.charAt(i) - 'a']) {

    cnt++;

    has[str.charAt(i) - 'a'] = true;
   }
  }

  int ans = 1;

  for (int i = 2; i <= cnt; i++)
   ans *= i;

  for (int i = cnt - k; i > 1; i--)
   ans /= i;
  return ans;
 }

 // Driver code 
 public static void main(String args[]) {
  String str = "rrpk";
  int k = 2;
  System.out.println(findPermutation(str, k));

 }
}
```

ALGO :
first count uniqe charecters in string then take k charecter from list of uniqe charecter and arrange them i.e  nPr = n! / (n – r)!.

Comment: K is not the number of unique charcters, for eg. s=aabbcdd the value of k may be k=3.